# How to make Storybook see SCSS Mixins?

Tags: css, sass, storybook, scss-mixins

I have two files:

**Node.tsx**
and
**Node.stories.tsx**

And there is the same piece of code

```
import IconSvg from 'ui/Icon/IconSvg'
import stylesNode from './Node.module.pcss'

// ..............
      return (
        <IconSvg
        className={stylesNode.propsIcon}
        onClick={onTextConfirm}
        />
      )
```

The code works fine everywhere, but the Storybook does not see the mixin css code

**Node.module.pcss**:

```
@mixin external {
  .propsIcon {
    margin: 0 -5px 0 15px;
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
  }
}
// And I have to add css classes without a mixin:
.propsIcon {
  margin: 0 -5px 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Otherwise, the class .propsIcon is simply not visible from the Storybook.

All css loaders are configured properly.
Storybook sees sass, scss, pcss.
Doesn't see only @mixin.

**Please tell me what is the problem here?**

This is my buildCssLoader for .storybook/webpack.config.ts:

```
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent')

export function buildCssLoader(isDev: boolean) {
    return {
        test: /\.(sacss|pcss|scss)$/i,
        use: [
            isDev ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                  modules: {
                      mode: 'local',
                      getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                  },
              },
            },
            'postcss-loader',
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
              },
            },
        ],
    };
}
```

Comment: It seems you've defined a mixin but you don't have an `@include` anywhere using it, so in theory its CSS shouldn't be available anywhere, Storybook or not. Can you provide an example of it working the way you want?

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I didn't write this application, there is a lot of legacy code. 

Started looking for @include and couldn't find it anywhere. 
Nevertheless, the application itself perfectly sees and uses this part of the code:
```
@mixin external {
  .propsIcon {
    margin: 0 -5px 0 15px;
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
  }
}
```